# Can we find MTD and YTD with ROLLUP function?

Tags: sql-server

Can we find MTD and YTD together using Rollup Function?
I am using it , for MTD data is correct but for YTD sales is not correct.
I want data in Product and Portfolio level that's why i rolled up it.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT "date", 
                Sum("daily_sales_y")               "DAILY_SALES_Y", 
                Sum("daily_sales_lyy")             DAILY_SALES_LYY, 
                Sum("daily_sales_m")               DAILY_SALES_M, 
                "businessdt_month", 
                "businessdt_year", 
                COALESCE("portfolio_role", ' SBU') "PORTFOLIO_ROLE", 
                "prod_name", 
                Sum("daily_sales_lym")             "DAILY_SALES_LYM",, 
"reportfilter" 
FROM   "c1" 
GROUP  BY "date", 
          "businessdt_month", 
          "businessdt_year", 
          "reportfilter", 
          rollup( "prod_name", "portfolio_role" )
```

Comment: This seems more like you need a `OVER` clause with a `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` clause or similar.

Comment: @Larnu I have already used it for calculating YTD in upper cte.

Comment: There is no CTE in your query though?

Comment: @Larnu But i have used and not getting correct output.

Comment: You need to show us your logic in your question then. If you have use a CTE you've omitted that from your question. Sample data, and expected results (as `text`, **not** a image) will greatly help us help you.

Comment: Please don't use 'obvious' acronyms, I've got no idea what MTD and YTD are.